# How to Integrate Linphone in an Existing Android Project

Tags: android, linphone

I am new to Linphone and I am having problem Regarding integration of linphone to my android project. As there are no enough Tutorial Regarding Linphone Libraries and How to Use it. So I would Like to reguest to Provide me step by step guide to help me regarding Integration of linphonoe to my android project

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Nice that you want to work on Linphone.. I am tryinh  from past 6 month and still no results..

Comment: @Prakash did ur linphone library run's ?? i also need help in this

Comment: @iPhnQ... No.. they didn't work. whenever I try to run the project from git, is shows that its missing avutils, neon etc libraries.

I tried to make it using the prepare.sh file but it stopped in middle with error.

Comment: @Prakash try out my answer i posted on your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086307/linphone-for-android-is-not-working-missing-libraries/18864971#18864971 ... accept my answer if it works for you

Answer (score 5):

After doing lots of research on android linphone, I have published two tutorials and add an excel sheet to setup and change code of android linphone. To setup android linphone project, you need to have Mac/Linux System. Here are links:-

1. [Android Linphone Tutorial-1](http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/04/start-working-on-linphone-android-part-1.html)
2. [Android Linphone Tutorial-2](http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/06/android-linphone-source-code-tutorial.html)

Comment: If I integrate liblinphone in my existing app, do I need a voip server to make audio video calls?

Comment: You can use your own server or can use Linphone server free of cost.

Comment: After integrating liblinphone to my app, how will I tell my app which server to use. In other words, which file to edit?

Answer (score 2):

Clone linphone-android project from git and build using android NDK R9. Build it on linux and before starting build, make sure that you have all the packages mentioned in README file.
To build the project, just type:

```
# make
```

and after successful compilation, generate linphone SDK using following command:

```
# make linphone-sdk
```

It will generate a zip file congaining linphone.jar file and native .so modules in different directories for different architectures.

Create a new android application project in eclipse, copy linphone.jar and other directories in libs directory under newly created android project, and refresh your project in eclipse. It will automatically add linphone.jar and other native linux (android) modules.

You are good to go... import packages in your android activities use the API.

Comment: After that how to start work on it? Any tutorial or guide line?

Comment: @MdMohsin have you find any solution for same?

Comment: @MdMohsin I checked that link. I am successfully make linphone and after I added project to Android studio. but I am getting error here: https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/issues/303
can you please help me to resolve this? and How to add linphone in my existing project? I need sip call functionality only.

Comment: Looks like you have forgot something to do at the time of Linphone building process else it will run well.

Comment: @Muhammadshahbaz If I integrate liblinphone in my existing app, do I need a voip server to make audio video calls?