# Linphone Android from git missing R.raw.rootca (ubuntu and win7)

Tags: android, git, ubuntu, android-ndk, linphone

[image]When I import the android project that I downloaded from the linphone repository link that is on the site:
**git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git --recursive**

The following is not right and also i have build issues...

```
copyIfNotExist(R.raw.rootca, mLinphoneRootCaFile);
```

I am a noob with makefile and NDK, i followed the instructions in the docs of linphone and managed to set up the hello_jni ... but linphone keeps eluding me.
even downloaded the mentioned ndk packages:

> download the Android ndk (>=r9d, < r10) from google and add it to your path (no symlink !!!).

I have tried ndk-r9d and ndk-r10b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this answer and you will be able to compile and import to eclipse without error.

[Linphone for android is not working/missing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18864971/2967875)

Answer (score 5):

Open samples in your linephone project directory then open raw directory in samples. There you will find rootca.pem file. Copy and paste it in your raw directory of root linephone project.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me what is the rootca.pem file used for?