# Can i build Linphone in Android Studio on Mac?

Tags: android, android-ndk, linphone

I think we can build it. But I am getting error to build it on Android Studio. First I download the Android Studio and NDK. Then add the PATH of Android Studio and NDK to the PATH Variable. When I run

```
./check_tools.sh
```

I get the output

```
Could not find automake. Please install it.
Could not find autoconf. Please install it.
Could not find pkg-config. Please install it.
Could not find ant. Please install it.
Could not find yasm. Please install it.
Could not find wget. Please install it.
Could not find libtoolize. Please install libtool.
Invalid version of nasm: your version does not support elf32 output format. If you have installed nasm, please check that your PATH env variable is set correctly.
Failed to detect required tools, aborting.
```

But i doubt whether i need these tool on Android Studio or not. When I run the project i get the error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load linphone-armeabi-v7a: findLibrary returned null.
```

Can anybody tell me the solution for that.

Comment: You've got the classic cross-compiler's headache compounded by being unfamiliar with the process.  Your best practical bet would be to see if someone else has port process figured out.  Otherwise, you may want to build it in (and targeting) a linux vm to get familiar with what is happening, before you try to cross build for a target on which these autoconfiguration steps can't run.

Comment: I found some tutorial for Eclipse but not a single for Android Studio.Its not the problem of Mac but Android Studio.

Comment: Neither eclipse nor android studio is meaningfully involved; this is an issue with the project and the ndk toolchain.

Comment: The actual error message you post occur because your mac is not configured to build this project to run on a mac, but then that isn't what you are wanting to do.  You will need to both install the missing tools and convince the project to build for android instead of the mac you are building on.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thank you for your comment. Can you tell me how can i download the missing tool ?

Comment: As I said in my first comment, I'd recommend you start by building this on linux for linux to gain understanding of the process of building the program (and the long list of tools it requires, appearing as your error messages) by doing so in its natural environment, before you try to port it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do this 
follow the **step by step guide** at this blog

[How to build culinphone on Android Studio using Mac OS X?](http://culinphone.wordpress.com)

http://culinphone.wordpress.com

**Here is a step to step guide.**
**Setup Linphone Sdk on Mac OS X
How to build Linphone in Android Studio on Mac?
Step by step guide :-**

Required Knowledge :-
Android Tools
Android Studio
A little bit about mac-terminal(shell)

S/W Requirements:-
Mac OS-X with these tools (You definetely need these tools to build linphone) :-

> coreutils, automake, autoconf, libtool, intltool, wget, pkgconfig ,cmake,
>   gmake, yasm, grep, doxygen, ImageMagick, optipng, antlr3

**STEP 1:-**
*Concerning these useful tools you can install the tools with this command*

```
$sudo port install coreutils automake autoconf libtool intltool wget pkgconfig cmake gmake yasm grep doxygen ImageMagick optipng antlr3
```

**STEP 2:-**
Check out these [Instructions how to upgrade nasm](https://theintobooks.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/installing-nasm/)

**STEP 3:-**
Then `install ant` by typing

```
brew update     #update if already installed
brew install ant
```

If you haven’t installed brew just type command give below

its a medium size download which takes 5 mins to download

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Just follow the process which involves installing various components. If you already have brew installed, make sure it’s up to date by executing:

```
brew update
```

Once installed you can simply type:

```
brew install ant
```

**STEP 4:-**
Now its time to install libtool. To install libtool run the command given below

```
 curl -OL http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/libtool/libtool-2.4.2.tar.gz
 tar -xzf libtool-2.4.2.tar.gz
 cd libtool-2.4.2
 ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

**STEP 5:-**
if you have not installed these programmes download and install
Download [Android Studio & SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
Download [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

**STEP 6:-**
Download git repository of LInphone Android by running command

```
$ sudo git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git –recursive
```

Now everything is configured perfectly

**STEP 7:-**
Open `terminal` and `cd into linphone-android`

Now when you get into the directory on terminal then check your `PATH of SDK & NDK` installed on your Mac run

```
$ echo $PATH
```

if you see the path with SDK and NDK location then it’s ok to proceed skip the below part and if not then you need to setup the PATH before you execute the make and make install script in

To setup path use:-

```
$export PATH=/Users/<yourusername>/android-sdks/platform-tools/:/Users//android-sdks/tools/:/Users//Documents/ndk/:/nobackup/local/prog/nasm/bin/:$PATH
```

it’s like `export PATH=(Path of your SDK platform tools folder):(Path of your SDK tools folder):(Path of your NDK folder):$PATH`

This will set up the path and to confirm again run

```
$ echo $PATH
```

Now if the Path is already setup you can simply run

```
$ make
```

Now connect your Device to you Mac and see if eclipse has detected it. After the device is connected run:

```
$ make install
```

Now if everythink is OK:-

After you have made your build then now you can import it into your Android Studio.

Open Android Studio

Import Project (Eclipse,ADT,Gradle,etc.) > select linphone-android > OK

Answer (score 0):

I am able to build the limphone on mac by follow the steps describe here  :-

[Linphone for android is not working/missing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086307/linphone-for-android-is-not-working-missing-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

You definetely need these tools to build linphone. 
Concerning nasm I had the same problem. You can use this site that instructs you how to upgrade to a newer nasm:

[Instructions how to upgrade nasm](https://theintobooks.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/installing-nasm/)

Concerning other useful tools you can install the tools below with this command:

```
$sudo port install coreutils automake autoconf libtool intltool wget pkgconfig cmake gmake yasm grep doxygen ImageMagick optipng antlr3
```

All these are found in the linphone build instructions README.md file.