# Couldn't find libtoolize, even though I have installed libtool in OSX Yosimite

Tags: android, macos, ant, linphone, libtool-xcode

I want to use Make install command and I have installed all requirements like yasm, nasm, curl, ant, rsync and the autotools: autoconf, automake, aclocal, pkgconfig, libtool. (Exactly, I want to compile Linphone Android NDK from Here : https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android. I have follow all steps from there)

I have try to install libtoolize using this command:

```
brew install libtoolize
```

But terminal always show :

> Error: No available formula for libtoolize

If i try to make install, terminal will show :

> Could not find libtoolize. Please install libtool.

Anybody can help ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should install the package `libtool` via

```
brew install libtool
```

This package contains the tool `libtoolize` as you can check via

```
brew list libtool
```

Note the warning

```
In order to prevent conflicts with Apple's own libtool we have prepended a "g"
so, you have instead: glibtool and glibtoolize.
```

You may try again installing the tools you want to. If the come with a `./configure` script, re-execute it to let it find `glibtoolize`. If this does not work, you may need to set the environment variable `LIBTOOL` to the version Homebrew installed:

```
export LIBTOOL=`which glibtool`
export LIBTOOLIZE=`which glibtoolize`
```

As a last resort, you may need to set a symbolic link from `glibtoolize` to `libtoolize`. You can do so via

```
ln -s `which glibtoolize` libtoolize
```

Then, add the directory with the link to the path by

```
export PATH=$(pwd):$PATH
```

Then, `libtoolize` should be found.

Comment: In your shell, just execute the `export` commands from the last box of my answer.

Comment: I have tried that, but still not worked (Could not find libtoolize. Please install libtool.)

Comment: Could you explain which tool you try to install and give a list of the commands you execute (preferably from unpacking the source archive to the error message)?

Comment: Okay, I have edited my question for detail, what exactly I want to try.

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: still can't find libtoolize, is pwd name of something that I must change based on my computer ?

Comment: No, that should work in your shell. Please post everything you did until you experienced the error message.

Comment: I follow step by step to make install (from the link), and the error showed, after that I tried export libtool and libtoolize, ln -s libtoolize, and export path, after that the same error showed again

Comment: There's an issue when installing libtool with brew: you may get an error like "/usr/local/bin/glibtoolize: line 406: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: No such file or directory". The solution that worked for me was 'brew unlink libtool' (this may not be necessary) and then 'brew uninstall libtool && brew install libtool' (ebothmann's comment at https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/43874).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should refer to this [Linphone for android is not working/missing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086307/linphone-for-android-is-not-working-missing-libraries/18864971#18864971). Autotools installation for mac as suggested a part of the step.

```
 # Assume we want to install them below $HOME/local.
 myprefix=$HOME/local

 # Ensure the tools are accessible from PATH.
 # It is advisable to set this also in ~/.profile, for development.
 PATH=$myprefix/bin:$PATH
 export PATH

 # Do the following in a scratch directory.
 wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/m4/m4-1.4.14.tar.gz
 wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-2.64.tar.gz
 wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-1.11.1.tar.gz
 wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libtool/libtool-2.4.tar.gz
 gzip -dc m4-1.4.14.tar.gz | tar xvf -
 gzip -dc autoconf-2.64.tar.gz | tar xvf -
 gzip -dc automake-1.11.1.tar.gz | tar xvf -
 gzip -dc libtool-2.4.tar.gz | tar xvf -
 cd m4-1.4.14
 ./configure -C --prefix=$myprefix && make && make install
 cd ../autoconf-2.64
 ./configure -C --prefix=$myprefix && make && make install
 cd ../automake-1.11.1
 ./configure -C --prefix=$myprefix && make && make install
 cd ../libtool-2.4
 ./configure -C --prefix=$myprefix && make && make install
```