# Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gnustl_shared from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, git, linphone, linphone-sdk

Hello Guys i Have a Problem with the Linephone android source code.Linephone provide us Open Source code for multiple Platforms.i am currently working with the LinePhone android source code from their git Repository for android.

Here What i Done.
1. Checkout the Source code form Git.url https://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/linphone/downloads

2.Open The Project into Android Studio
3.After Successfully Build it Just Run the Project

its Run Success fully But i got this Error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gnustl_shared from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/org.linphone-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/org.linphone-1]: findLibrary returned null
                                                                  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
                                                                  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
                                                                  at org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.<clinit>(LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.java:51)
                                                                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217) 
                                                                  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172) 
                                                                  at org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreFactory.instance(LinphoneCoreFactory.java:47) 
                                                                  at org.linphone.LinphoneService.onCreate(LinphoneService.java:299) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2529) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

At the Line

```
System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");
```

honestly i dont know why i am getting this error and what is gnustl_shared ?
Let me Help to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using your install manager (Depending on your device like `aptitude` or `homebrew` or `macports` ) install `gnustl` and `gnu` related (like `libstdc++6:i386` `libgcc1:i386` `zlib1g:i386` `libncurses5:i386` )  which is needed for liblinphone

Refer : https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android#compilation-instructions

[Couldn't find libtoolize, even though I have installed libtool in OSX Yosimite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535735/couldnt-find-libtoolize-even-though-i-have-installed-libtool-in-osx-yosimite)